# Should I use "is needed" or "is in need"?

Tags: grammar

I am writing my master's thesis now, and I got a small question on the two terms in the title. You probably noticed, my English sucks...

I have a sentence like: "this model is needed", but I want to change the to sentence to "this model is in need". Is that correct?

Comment: Neither one makes any sense outside of context. What model is "this model"? What kind of model is it? Does it exist already? Who needs what, in other words.

Answer (score 3):

The two mean different things. "Mary is needed" means that there is something or someone that needs Mary. "Mary is in need" means that Mary needs something or someone.

For example:

- "This model is needed to correctly calculate the correlation". If we don't have the model, we can't calculate the correlation.
- "This model is in need of a better statistical module to correctly predict the results" If the model doesn't have a better statistical module it will predict wrong results.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You have saved me from embrassing myself in front of prof...Thank you, thank you, thank you!